# Why won't my flat-screen TV work with Ubuntu?

Tags: graphics

Why will the same graphics card that allowed me to use the flat screen TV when running Windows not display with Ubuntu? Keep it simple please. I am new to Linux, still feeling my way around.

Comment: A lot more information is need in order to help you, what graphics card do you have, what connection (DVI?). The more the merrier, if you want you can start by describing how was your windows connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the Unity desktop: Click on the top left Ubuntu Logo and search for monitors. Click detect monitors.

If you're running Gnome: Click on the appearance menu under system and find monitor. Click detect monitors.

If this doesn't work more details would help to alleviate the problem.

Comment: Standard monitor cable, windows xp just accepted it as a screen; The machine is a Packard Bell imedia with integrated graphics card GEforce 5200